# Insertar mensaje tooltip

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tooltip

Deseo insertar un mensaje tooltip en la parte de inicio asi como en "cambiar contraseña", "cerrar session", etc. ¿Como se realiza correctamente esa implementación?

[image: Ejemplo a modificar]

Comment: ¿En que lenguaje es esto?

Comment: C# en visual studio @LucianoMontañez

Comment: Que versión de Visual Studio ocupas? 2012, 2013, 2015 o 2017?

Comment: @SSVITT visual 2017

Comment: Esta pregunta confunde las versiones del visual studio con las versiones del lenguaje (que son indistintas y la que importa es la version del lenguaje) y tambien confunde porque no dice que tecnologia de vista esta siendo usada (wpf, winforms, uwp)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

yo me he quedado rezagado con las versiones de Visual Studio ya que estoy trabajando con la versión 2010 pero no creo que cambie radicalmente la forma de hacerlo:

Yo lo hago de esta manera, no digo que sea la única forma de hacerlo pero a mi me ha funcionado. Describo como lo hago:

1. Desde el Cuadro de Herramientas, Arrastras el componente `ToolTip` a
   tu form.
2. Ahora al seleccionar un elemento de tu menú, en tu caso INICIO. Verás que en la ventana de **propiedades** (en esa parte donde cambias el nombre, el texto, y las demás propiedades...) aparece un elemento que se llama **ToolTipText**, ahí agregas el texto que quieres que se muestre y al ejecutar el frm y pasar el mouse por encima del elemento, aparecerá el `ToolTip`.

Espero te sirva de referencia para lo que pretendes hacer.

Comment: Y como lo selecciono un mensaje personalizado para por ejemplo cerrar sesiion,cambiar contraseña etc

Comment: Tienes que seleccionar tu elemento CABIAR CONTRASEÑA y agregas texto para el Tooltip, seleccionas CERRAR SESION y agregas texto al ToolTip y así sucesivamente para los casos que desees, espero haber entendido tu pregunta.

Comment: si esta bien tu idea,pero no me aparece nada aun sigue los mismo pasos

Comment: No aparece los ToolTips al ejecutar la aplicación?

Comment: no :/ no aparece nada

Comment: Podría servirte [este hilo](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/90f20333-2b70-402f-8435-104ac1ed2b5f/menustrip-con-tooltip?forum=vbes)